# Как можно объединить два фрейма в один?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, анализ-данных, обработка-данных

Есть два df:

```
a = pd.DataFrame([{'id': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 0},
                  {'id': 1, 'b': 7, 'c': 2},
                  {'id': 1, 'b': 4, 'c': 2},
                  {'id': 1, 'b': 5, 'c': 2},
                  {'id': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 2},
                  {'id': 2, 'b': 3, 'c': 2},
                  {'id': 2, 'b': 0, 'c': 2},
                  {'id': 2, 'b': 2, 'c': 2},
                  {'id': 3, 'b': 2, 'c': 2},
                  {'id': 3, 'b': 2, 'c': 2},
                  {'id': 3, 'b': 5, 'c': 2},
                  {'id': 3, 'b': 2, 'c': 1}])

b = pd.DataFrame([{'id': 1, 'b': 7, 'c': 2},
                  {'id': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 2},
                  {'id': 1, 'b': 8, 'c': 7},
                  {'id': 1, 'b': 5, 'c': 2},
                  {'id': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 2},
                  {'id': 2, 'b': 3, 'c': 2},
                  {'id': 2, 'b': 2, 'c': 9},
                  {'id': 2, 'b': 2, 'c': 2},
                  {'id': 3, 'b': 7, 'c': 2},
                  {'id': 3, 'b': 2, 'c': 2},
                  {'id': 3, 'b': 5, 'c': 2},
                  {'id': 3, 'b': 2, 'c': 1}])
```

Как можно объединить их в один, но id в df b должны измениться в зависимости от последнего id в df a, на выходе нужно получить:

```
    pd.DataFrame([{'id': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 0},
                  {'id': 1, 'b': 7, 'c': 2},
                  {'id': 1, 'b': 4, 'c': 2},
                  {'id': 1, 'b': 5, 'c': 2},
                  {'id': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 2},
                  {'id': 2, 'b': 3, 'c': 2},
                  {'id': 2, 'b': 0, 'c': 2},
                  {'id': 2, 'b': 2, 'c': 2},
                  {'id': 3, 'b': 2, 'c': 2},
                  {'id': 3, 'b': 2, 'c': 2},
                  {'id': 3, 'b': 5, 'c': 2},
                  {'id': 3, 'b': 2, 'c': 1},
                  {'id': 4, 'b': 7, 'c': 2},
                  {'id': 4, 'b': 2, 'c': 2},
                  {'id': 4, 'b': 8, 'c': 7},
                  {'id': 4, 'b': 5, 'c': 2},
                  {'id': 4, 'b': 2, 'c': 2},
                  {'id': 5, 'b': 3, 'c': 2},
                  {'id': 5, 'b': 2, 'c': 9},
                  {'id': 5, 'b': 2, 'c': 2},
                  {'id': 6, 'b': 7, 'c': 2},
                  {'id': 6, 'b': 2, 'c': 2},
                  {'id': 6, 'b': 5, 'c': 2},
                  {'id': 6, 'b': 2, 'c': 1}])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
res = a.append(b.assign(id=b["id"]+a["id"].max())).reset_index(drop=True)
```

результат:

```
In [312]: res
Out[312]:
    id  b  c
0    1  2  0
1    1  7  2
2    1  4  2
3    1  5  2
4    1  2  2
5    2  3  2
6    2  0  2
7    2  2  2
8    3  2  2
9    3  2  2
10   3  5  2
11   3  2  1
12   4  7  2
13   4  2  2
14   4  8  7
15   4  5  2
16   4  2  2
17   5  3  2
18   5  2  9
19   5  2  2
20   6  7  2
21   6  2  2
22   6  5  2
23   6  2  1
```